# Instructions on building CMOS camera wifi video transmission

Tags: wifi, camera

I am not sure this is the appropriate place to ask this kind of question, but I believe this is the best community to ask. I'd like to learn how to build my own circuit that would be capable of streaming video from a CMOS camera like this:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11745

I don't want to use Arduino or Raspberry Pi. I need a smaller PCB that focuses purely on the video transmission. It doesn't need to run Linux or do anything else. I know decent amount about electronics, so I should be able to follow instructions. I can't find anything online. Does anyone know about a webpage that sheds more light on how to design such a board? It can be built from smaller board components, but it has to be smaller and lighter than using Arduino or Raspberry Pi. Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to have a board with a controller that initializes and sends commands to the controller? Do you want a wireless connection so you can start video capture remotely? Also, that camera has NTSC output, so it's not immediately compatible with computers which use RGB for display. Surely there are conversion programs though, it's really no chore.

Comment: Thanks! Wireless connection to start the video remotely would be nice, yes. If a different type of a camera exists that would be more appropriate for this solution than the NTSC camera, I am open to switching to it. The key feature is low latency camera streaming from a wifi connection.

Answer (score 3):

The unit that you linked to is what is known in the industry as a board camera.  It outputs NTSC formatted analog video so it's as simple as just supplying power and connecting the video signal to either an analog input TV or VCR or an convertor for displaying on your computer.  It's really about connecting up connectors.  I'd suggest a "wall wart" type power supply that and a RCA type plug for the video.

Comment: Thanks! Now, the hard part - how do I stream it over wifi? Are there small boards that I can purchase for this purpose or is there a page somewhere where I can learn how to build my own PCB taking the signal from the camera and streaming it over wifi?

Comment: @pkout, Do you know much about programming microcontrollers? I can see on your profile that you have a least some experience using the Arduino. Actually, if you don't already know, the microcontroller on the Arduino board is an AtMega328P from Atmel, the rest of the components on the board are just for filtering, UART to USB conversions, regulation and the like. So, you can actually take the AtMega328P, mount it on your own PCB with the appropriate passive components and go from there. You can even still use the Arduino libraries by burning their bootloader program to the chip.

Comment: Oh, you're right! So I can basically look up how to do this using Arduino and then implement it using the microcontroller itself. The only problem with this might be that the other controller will be a wifi shield that goes on top of the arduino and I don't want something that big. I am not sure that I can just remove the chip on those and connect it directly to AtMega. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Pkout, well you certainly can but it wouldn't likely end up being much smaller than the board you can already buy with the device mounted. There are also [bluetooth solutions](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=bluetooth%20arduino&sprefix=bluetooth+arduin%2Caps) that are much smaller depending on the distance.